# Illegalaccessexception generated on class basecontainer using reflection while deploying application on glassfish

Tags: java-8, glassfish, ejb, runtimeexception, illegalaccessexception

On migration application from `glassfish 3` to `glassfish 5` and `jdk-6` to `jdk-8`, I am getting following error on console. What could be the possible reasons for EJB not getting deployed on glassfish server?

```
 Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer
 load method java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization
 error at
 org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)

 ...

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
 com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer can not access a member of class
 my.package.$Proxy280 with modifiers "public">       at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
```

Comment: There was an interface with default access level in services package, on adding public modifier this issue solved.